# Animated background in Java

Tags: java, video, background

I want to ask if someone knows how I can put a video "background" in Java. Especially, I want to put white noise like the snow on TV like a background for important reason. Has anyone an idea?
Thank you

Comment: You mean a background for the IDE or a background for your application ? Could you be more specific ?

Comment: Please, don't include your IDE, it has nothing to do with the programming language itself (and with this question)

Comment: Sorry,a background for my application.

Comment: Can animated GIF helps me? Sorry,I am a beginer,so you can understand me.
I want something like this ( http://www.google.gr/imgres?imgurl=http://www.coins-bloc.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/white-noise2.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.coins-bloc.com/white-noise/&h=768&w=1024&sz=315&tbnid=jbcxpHz1GcHYJM:&tbnh=92&tbnw=123&zoom=1&usg=__6KWYnc2lGg9gg_2PHO7bUSbsAVI=&docid=rTZR10hQCkK_8M&sa=X&ei=icp6Ut3eK4SWtAb8oIGgDQ&ved=0CG0Q9QEwBQ ),but in video.
Thank you !

Comment: @BackSlash ok,sorry !